# How to add or remove a value on an array?

Tags: java, arrays

1st quesiton :

How do i remove from an array ? Basically the parameter will specify which index will be removed.
I will have to update this in a new array and return it.

```
int[] removeFromArray(int[] array, int index) {
    int[] newArray = array
}
```

2nd quesiton:

I guess same concept, but i have to add to an array.

Conditions:
I cant use `ArrayUtils` , etc.

I'm guessing this can be done using `for` loops ?

Cheers

Comment: why not use list replace array ?

Comment: Try *something*. Post your code and tell us which line you're having problems with.  This us not a coding service (although sometimes I wonder...)

Comment: Do your homework yourself, kid.

Comment: You should think more carefully about which data structures are appropriate for your use case. It sounds like you shouldn't be using a raw array at all.

Comment: I think you need to clarify the (very significant) differences between an `array` and a `list` (ah, I see user2398318 has beat me to it)

Answer (score 1):

if you really want to remove element from array , you can do following

```
static int[] removeFromArray(int[] s, int idx)
{
    int[] dest = new int[s.length-1];
    System.arraycopy(s, 0, dest, 0, idx);
    System.arraycopy(s, idx+1, dest, idx, s.length-idx-1);      
    return dest;
}
```

I would suggest consider other options like 'ArrayList' or suggestions made by Thihara.

Comment: Thanks, but im using blueJ. For our homework we are not allowed to use those libraries..

Answer (score 0):

You can't add or remove from an array.

You can however set the elements in the array to `null`, or set a separate value.

If you want to remove an array you will have to create a new array and assign the elements you don't want to remove manually.

Alternatively you can shift the elements downward so only the last index of an element will be removed.

Rather than do all of this manually please look into java's ArrayList(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and Collection API(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/
)

Answer (score 0):

You can not remove anything from an array as they are immutable. Although, you can create a new array that does not contain the elements you want

```
public int[] removeFromArray(int[] array,int index){
    int[] newArray = new int[array.length - 1];
    for(int i = 0;i<array.length;i++){
        if(i == index){
            continue;
        }else{
            if(i>index && i!= (index+1)){
                newArray[i-1] = array[i];
            }else{
                newArray[i] = array[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Please clarify what you mean by **add an array**. Are you trying to say that add the values of all the elements of two arrays and display them ?

Assuming you want to add `int[]` arrays together, you can do that as follows:

```
public int[] addTwoArrays(int[] array1,int[] array2){
    if(array1.length != array2.length){
        System.out.println("Can not add arrays of different lengths.");
        return null;
    }else{
        int[] additionArray = new int[array1.length]; // or array[2].length cause they are the same length;
        for(int i = 0;i<array1.length;i++){
            additionArray[i] = array1[i] + array2[i];
        }
    }
    return additionArray;
}
```

Comment: Remember to shift elements whose indices are higher than `index`.

Comment: @Lonenebula ah yes I forgot that ! My code will generate an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` I changed the code. Have a look !

Comment: You may want to change the second `if`-statement in the `removeFromArray` method to this: `if(i > index) { newArray[i - 1] = array[i]; }`

Comment: @user2368650 You can give it a +1 or accept this as an answer :)